# How to query in terms of two columns in laravel eloquent orm

Tags: php, sql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I need help to make a query in laravel.
I have three tables

1)Category(Contains id and name column).

2)Geometry(Contains id and name column).

3)practical(Contains id and name column and the Category_id,Geometry_id column/keys )

Now i want to search the practicals in  terms of Category_id and Geometry_id.
The Practical.php model file is..

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Model;
use App\Models\Practical;

class Practical extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $table='practical';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [

    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
    }

    public function geometry()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Geometry');
    }

}
```

The Category and Geometry Model  code is

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Model;
use App\Models\Geometry;

class Geometry extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $table='geometry';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [

    ];



     public function practical()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Practical');
    }


}
```

I know how to query using only one ID.Category or geometry like this..

```
$Categories=Category::where('id',1)->firstOrFail();
```

but i failed to query by checking both the ids of Category and Geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now i want to search the practicals in terms of Category_id and Geometry_id

If you want to search practicals by category ID and geometry ID, just do a simple query:

```
Practical::where('category_id', $categoryId)
         ->where('geometry_id', $geometryId)
         ->get();
```